# MVVM-Light => Pass Command Parameter AND EventArgs to Command

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm-light, commandparameter, eventtocommand

Using `MVVM-Light Toolkit` in Silverlight 5, i am trying to find a way to pass `Command Parameters` **AND** `EventArgs` both to ViewModel in an Event-To-Command behavior.

I did find a post suggesting Passing EventArgs as Command Parameters but in my case i want to use `EventArgs` and `Command Parameter` both in ViewModel.

Anyone can help?

Comment: is this even possible using MVVM-Light toolkit?

Comment: I would create a lightweight object that contains the information I need from the event args and the object I was normally going to send as the command parameter and just use that new lightweight object as my command parameter.

Comment: @StewartSweet Sorry but how can you create such an object in view? can you kindly show an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved the Issue .... in case if anyone else is wondering ...

Concept : We only need to pass the EventArgs via MVVM-Light Event to Command. In event to Command, there is a property **Source**. we can cast this 'Source' Property to the object that  generated this command.

Example :

we declare command with eventargs in ViewModel Constructor

```
FilterQuotationsCommand = new RelayCommand<GridViewFilteredEventArgs>(FilterQuotationsCommandExecute);
```

And we Access the Sender via the "Source" after casting it to the sending control.

```
private void FilterQuotationsCommandExecute(GridViewFilteredEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (RadGridView) e.Source; // we casted the Source to Grid
        var item = grid.SelectedItem;      // we can access grid's selected items
    }
```